# Unknown Column Left Join MySQL

Tags: mysql, left-join

I've used the "NOT IN (select)" Function, but it takes too long to load on several registers. So I want to improve the query using LEFT JOIN, but I don't know what's wrong. I'm getting `#1054 - Unknown column 'a.id_logistica' in 'on clause'`.
The column "id_logistica" in table "logistica" does exists, as it does in "det_log" table. This is the code:

```
SELECT 
  a.*, a.id_logistica, 
  b.nombre username, c.placa, 
  b.nombre scliente, e.nombre ruta,
  d.nombre_con, clase 
FROM 
  logistica a,  cliente b,
  vehiculo c,  conductores d, ruta e 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
  det_log t2 ON  t2.id_logistica = a.id_logistica
WHERE 
  a.id_cliente = b.id_cliente  AND  a.id_ruta = e.id_ruta 
  AND t2.id_logistica IS NULL AND a.id_vehiculo = c.id_vehiculo 
  AND a.id_conductor = d.id_conductor AND activo = 1 
  and finalizado = 0  AND ( a.id_ruta > 1 OR a.borrado = 9 ) 
ORDER BY 
  fecha_des DESC
```

Comment: Just a wild guess, but maybe it is because you are mixing the two join syntaxes, ie logistica a, cliente b...etc, and LEFT OUT JOIN. Try just left joining only with logistica a to see if it works.

Comment: Are you sure id_logistica exists in det_log? Don't the b,c,d,e tables have primary and foreign keys that can be joined on?

Comment: Yes. They both exist.

Answer (score 0):

if your query was running, you can try this one :

```
SELECT 
    a.*, a.id_logistica, 
    b.nombre username, c.placa, 
    b.nombre scliente, e.nombre ruta,
    d.nombre_con, clase 
FROM logistica a
Left Join cliente b On b.id_cliente = a.id_cliente
Left Join vehiculo c On c.id_vehiculo = a.id_vehiculo
Left Join conductores d On d.id_conductor = a.id_conductor
Left Join ruta e On e.id_ruta = a.id_ruta
Left Join det_log t2 On t2.id_logistica = a.id_logistica
WHERE ( a.id_ruta > 1 OR a.borrado = 9 )
    And activo = 1
    And finalizado = 0
    And t2.id_logistica IS NULL 
ORDER BY fecha_des DESC
```

but, if i look the error. it's mean nothing column "id_logistica" in table "logistica".

please check column in table "logistica".

```
desc logistica;
```

maybe, you wrong to write.